# How to retrive specifc Layer from Here Map JS?

Tags: here-api

I add DataPoints into Provider then into Layer which is bundled into the map.

Later I want to edit some of DataPoints, to do this I need to retrieve layer then provider from the map.

I try it by getting an array of layers but I won't know which one is a layer with my dataPoints.

```
let clusterDataProvider = new H.clustering.Provider(dataPoints, {
          clusteringOptions: {
            eps: 16,
            minWeight: 2,
            strategy: H.clustering.Provider.Strategy.GRID
          },
          theme: {
            getClusterPresentation: this.getClusterPresentation,
            getNoisePresentation: this.getNoisePresentation
          }
        })
      }),
let layer = hereMap.getLayers().asArray().find(layer => layer instanceof H.map.layer.ObjectLayer)
    if(!layer) {
      layer = new H.map.layer.ObjectLayer(clusterDataProvider)
      hereMap.addLayer(layer, 0);
    }
    layer.getProvider()
```

But ofc there can be a lot of `ObjectLayers` in my map, so how can I recognize which one is that with `clusterDataProvider`.

Or anyone has a better idea of how to edit a specific layer or cluster provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the layer by utilize this code:

```
function findClusterLayer(hereMap){
    let layer = hereMap.getLayers().asArray().find(layer => {
      let isObjLayer = layer instanceof H.map.layer.ObjectLayer;
      return isObjLayer && (layer.getProvider() instanceof H.clustering.Provider);
  });
  return layer;
}
```

Unfortunately, you can't get dataPoints nor from layer nor from cluster provider, use please workaround like this:

```
var clusteringLayer = new H.map.layer.ObjectLayer(clusteredDataProvider);
clusteringLayer.$data = dataPoints;
```

later you can get datapoints like this:

```
var layer = findClusterLayer(map);
var dataPoints = layer.$data;
```

after changing some datapoints save it to cluster:

```
clusteredDataProvider.setDataPoints(dataPoints);
```

See please [complete example](https://jsfiddle.net/gw0k5fnq/1/)

BTW: you can save some object into every datapoint see please documentation on https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.20.0/api_reference/H.clustering.DataPoint.html#data